# SSO implementation for GAE web application

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, saml

I am trying to integrate the single sign on for my application running on Google app engine platform.
I am using SAML 2.0 protocol to get this done. My organization already have the identity provider using LDAP, which configured in such a format (https://sso-companyname/appname). For this configuration, its took following details

1. XML metadata for their assertion consumer service (ACS) (https://www.google/companyname/a/acs),
2. a list of the LDAP attributes to be sent (email),
3. which attribute is to be used as the subject of the assertion (company enterprise id),
4. the RelayState URL at the relying party site to send the user after the SAML Response assertion has been validated, (application target URL form GAE deployment. like (https://appname-dot-projectid.appspot.com)
5. a short name (less than 7 characters) of the application to be used in the URL, (given as app name)

According to this configuration, the ACS is not for a particular GAE application, so I am getting 400 error from the google server.

Can some one help me on how to create ACS for a single GAE application and would able to explain the SSO for GAE web application would be grateful.

The web application using Python jinja2 frame-work for the UI, webapp2 for the routing. It will call the google-big-query to populate the data to UI, currently, it is using Python standard environment of GAE, and OAuth 2 method to authenticate and call the big-query API to get data. So some people don't have the GCP/Project access, doesn't able to view the data. to resolve this we trying to implement SSO on top of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to integrate GAE with SSO/SAML is to use [Google Identity Platform (GIP)](https://console.cloud.google.com/customer-identity/providers) which uses Firebase under the hood.  This lets you use the `firebase-admin` Python package to easily interact with JWTs, and lets you use the GIP console to set up an SAML server.